# Shipping libstdc++.so.6 with application

Tags: c++, linker, libstdc++

I want to use gcc 4.8.1 for my application (requires libstdc++.so.6.0.18), however customers only have libstdc++.so.6.0.13. I have been using `-static-libgcc -static-stdlibc++` for a while now, but my application consists of several dynamically linked libraries and one main application.  This means that when compiling each dynamic library, they must statically compile the standard library, which is redundant and wasteful.  I want to just ship the standard library of my choice with my product, however every time I run my application in an environment like theirs, it always loads the wrong standard library.  It prefers the `/usr/lib64/` version no matter what I seem to do (it seems to take precedence over `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

Constraints:

1. I'm not allowed to force them to upgrade to a new standard library.
2. I don't want to make the dynamic libraries static.  (I'd be able to statically compile everything into the main app once, but there are some logistical barriers that prevent me from recompiling some libraries into static ones).

`-Wl,-rpath=$(path_to_directory)` is a bit dangerous, however it is legal because the customers do source some settings that allow me to set path variables.  However, setting the rpath of my new stdlibc++ doesn't seem to be overriding the default `/usr/lib64` version.  I still get `GLIBCXX` errors because it won't use the right library.

Surely there is an elegant solution for this?

Perhaps there is just an error in my procedure.  Here's an example (sorry about the censor, but it's just username stuff):

```
~/example$ pwd
/home/username/example
~/example$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

~/example$ ls
Makefile  libstdc++.so.6.0.18  test.cpp
~/example$ make
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror test.cpp -o test
~/example$ ldd test
./test: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by ./test)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe5919000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x000000390b800000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003904800000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000000390b400000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003904400000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003904000000)
~/example$ setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/username/example
~/example$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/username/example
~/example$ ldd test
./test: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by ./test)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2d3ff000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x000000390b800000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003904800000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000000390b400000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003904400000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003904000000)
```

Sorry guys, I made a rather dumb mistake...

```
~/example$ file libstdc++.so.6.0.18 
libstdc++.so.6.0.18: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

Some dweeb built the wrong version of the library, and another dweeb (namely myself) tried using it on a 64-bit machine.  Using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was working all along...

Comment: I would have expected LD_LIBRARY_PATH to work: Did you try `ldd`ing your binary both with and without LD_LIBRARY_PATH set? Also remember that LD_LIBRARY_PATH will never persist through elevations.

Comment: Show how you are setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and also the output of `ldd $x | fgrep ++` where `$x` ranges over all binaries you ship, with LD_LIBRARY_PATH set and/or `-Wl,-rpath=` in effect.

Comment: Okay so `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is supposed to take precedence?  My application runs in user mode, so there are no elevated privs.  Here's what I basically did: Compile with gcc 4.8.1 (its configuration resolves links with the correct library), set `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/myusername/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`, and then try to run/`ldd` the program.  The stdlib I want in this example is in my home directory.  This is supposed to take precedence over system paths?

Comment: Can you try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/username/example` because I think setenv is just treating it as a shell variable.

Comment: I'm in cshell, and so are the customers sadly.

Comment: Does setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` supersede the system library path for `libstdc++.so` in you shells?

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH should take precedence over directories cached by ldconfig. Be careful using `/home/myusername/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`, if LD_LIBRARY_PATH is initially empty then that sets it to `/home/myusername/:` and the empty component means "look in the current working directory" which is a security risk.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that the executable is linked to the soname `libstdc++.so.6` not to the full library filename `libstdc++.so.6.0.16`. The dynamic linker will look for `libstdc++.so.6` in the usual places (i.e. LD_LIBRARY_PATH, DT_RPATH, ldconfig dirs etc.) so  to ensure the 6.0.18 version is found you need a symlink called `libstdc++.so.6` pointing to it.

Instead of using LD_LIBRARY_PATH (which is fragile on machines you don't control, because users might alter their environment) I prefer linking with `'-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN'` (N.B. the quotes are necessary to stop the shell expanding `$ORIGIN`)

An RPATH of `$ORIGIN` tells the dynamic linker to start looking for shared libraries in the same directory as the executable, so if you ship libstdc++.so alongside your executable it will be found. If you want to ship the executable in a `bin` directory and have the library in a `lib` directory you can use `'-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../lib'` or other paths relative to the location of the executable.

Comment: Ahh I've seen that ORIGIN thing before, but I didn't realize it was a keyword for the linker; I thought it was just a commonly used shell variable (which would be entirely counterproductive).